# What are the system created files in $HOME?

Tags: filesystem, home-directory

I'm writing a home backup routine and want to omit certain files and directories from everyone's home folder. I'm planning to omit all of these, but here's the question. What are they used for?

**Directories:**

```
.cache
.compiz
.config
.dbus
.dmrc
.gconf
.gnome2
.gnome2_private
.gvfs
.ICEauthority
.local
```

**Files:**

```
examples.desktop
.lesshst
.Xauthority
.xinputrc
.xsession-errors
.xsession-errors.old
```

Comment: The home folder contains the user's data files and user-specific configuration files and you probably don't want to omit them from your backup.

Answer (score 2):

These files and folders contain user specific setting. Desktop behavior and Application setting of each user is not same. These settings are stored in their home directory in hidden files and directory.

If you backup your whole home directory including the configuration files and folders, after restore,your settings also will be restored to its previous state.

Comment: Your right enough, but i just want to save minimal and avoid restoring items which may recreate an issue after recovery & reload.Can anyone throw some technical info in.